# Trouble creating a Binary Tree class with a nested "TreeNode" class in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inner-classes, assignment-operator

I'm trying to just create a simple binary tree to store integers.  I don't want to just create a `struct node` outside of my `class BinaryTree` and then instantiate an object of `node*` inside the `BinaryTree` class.  I want to *embed* the `node` class in the `BinaryTree` class.

Here is the header file I've written so far for the project:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree {
private:
    class TreeNode {
    public:
        int Data;
        TreeNode* Right;
        TreeNode* Left;
        TreeNode() : Right(nullptr), Left(nullptr) {}
        TreeNode(int data, TreeNode* lnode = nullptr, TreeNode* rnode=nullptr) :
        Data(data), Right(rnode), Left(lnode) {}
    };
    TreeNode* root;
public:
    BinaryTree();
    bool Empty() const;
    bool NewNode(TreeNode* node, const int& new_element);
    bool Insert(TreeNode* node, const int& new_element);    

};
#endif
```

Here is the .cpp realization of these declarations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BinaryTree::BinaryTree() : root(nullptr) {

}

bool BinaryTree::Empty() const
{
    return (root == nullptr) ? true : false;
}

bool BinaryTree::NewNode(TreeNode* node, const int& new_element)
{
        TreeNode* new_node;
        new_node = new TreeNode;
        new_node->Data = new_element;
        node = new_node;
        return true;
}

bool BinaryTree::Insert(TreeNode* node, const int& new_element)
{
    if (Empty())
    {
        return NewNode(node, new_element);
    }
    else if (new_element < node->Data) 
    {
        return node->Left = Insert(node->Left, new_element);
    }
    else 
    {
        return node->Right = Insert(node->Right, new_element);
    }
}
```

The specific errors I'm looking at have to do with the `bool BinaryTree::Insert` function.  I get error notifs on the assignment operator `=` at these two places:

(1): `return node->Left = Insert(node->Left, new_element);`

(2): `return node->Right = Insert(node->Right, new_element);`

The following error message shows up when I investigate:

> E0513  a value of type "bool" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "BinaryTree::TreeNode *

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this error or what it's specifically addressing.  Other examples of a binary search tree with an embedded class utilize these techniques, and yet I cannot make these assignment operators work.  I have also tried to change the return type of the functions, without any success.

Comment: `Insert` returns a bool.  `node->Left = Insert(...)` assigns the return value from that function to the member `Left` on `node`.  The error is saying this doesn't make sense because that's a pointer, to which you're trying to assign a bool value.

Comment: The node class should not be visible in the tree's interface; it is the tree's responsibiity to manage nodes, not the user's. You want to write `BinaryTree tree; tree.insert(2); tree.insert(789);`, and you want private recursive helper functions.

Comment: Unrelated: `return (root == nullptr) ? true : false;`  --> `return root == nullptr;`

Comment: Also unrelated: `const int&` --> `int`. Passing by const reference is more efficient than passing by value for bigger objects, certainly not for fundamental types.

Comment: Where are you deallocating your memory? I would recommend using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. You should virtually never use `new` and `delete`, [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) are easier to use and safer.

Comment: @paddy  Yeah, that's something I've been battling for a while.  I keep going back to that error when I try to do anything with the enclosed/embedded class.  I'm just such a newbie, that I'm not sure how to rectify the issue.

Comment: @molbdnilo  Yeah, that's definitely what I'm trying to institute, and after your comment, I'm cleaning up the implementation so that the user doesn't have to mess around with any nodes.

Comment: @Debaug  At this point, I haven't gotten to deallocating memory in the program.  To be honest, we haven't really covered that aspect in the course, so I'm not sure about all of the finer points of it, but part of the project is making sure to deallocate the memory.